# Can't get data from store.getNewRecords() after use store.add(record)

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I'm new developer extjs. I want to get add new record from store after add store.add(record). i use sytax like below

```
var newRecord = store.getNewRecords()
console.log('newRecord',newRecord);
```

but i can't get new record, i got output data like this newRecord:[]
Please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to add records to store and commit changes,then get new records.

```
 grid_store.add({'Name':"ab",'dob':"099"})
     grid_store.commitChanges();
     var newRecord = grid_store.getNewRecords()
     console.log('newRecord',newRecord);
 });
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2p78md5t/3/

Comment: i have added grid_store.commitChanges(), but i still get newRecord : [] in console

Comment: Are you able to see the added record in grid .Can u share your code here or in fiddle.

Comment: Can you go to your scirpt in jsfiddle click on Run then  use chrome browser  right click and click on Inspect  you will see newRecord : [] in console

Comment: No not that what is printing in console.I m talking about the record that you have added using store.add() .Are u able to see the newly added record in the grid

Comment: yes, i see newly added record in the grid, but i want also to get newRecord and show it in console